# How to maintain class state when executing class methods for multiple classes in parallel?

Tags: class, python-3.x, state, python-multiprocessing

In the below example, how to increment `n` when using multiprocessing?

```
class Test:  
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        self.n += 1
        return True

# Generate 4 classes
klasses = [Test(0) for i in range(4)]
```

When `[k.n for k in klasses]` is run it produces `[0, 0, 0, 0]` as expected.

Trying to run the function `run()` for each class in parallel using:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool    
with Pool() as pool:
    results = [pool.apply_async(k.run, ()) for k in klasses ]
    result = [i.get() for i in results]
```

results in `result` returning `[True, True, True, True]` as expected. The class' `n` attribute has not changed though as running `[k.n for k in klasses]` results in `[0, 0, 0, 0]`.

When the method is not processed in parallel e.g. `[k.run() for k in klasses]`, `[k.n for k in klasses]` returns `[1, 1, 1, 1]` as expected.

Is there a way for the classes to maintain state when run in parallel though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared state in `multiprocessing` must be done explicitly, since each worker is a separate process. The [`multiprocessing` docs cover the various options in so detail.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) The simplest solution would be to make `n` a [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value), though that requires significant changes in the `Test` class to make it use the proper types and attributes.

Alternatively, try and find a way to perform your work using `pool.imap`/`pool.imap_unordered` with state being passed in as arguments and new data returned; if your problem can be expressed this way, it's often better to limit sharing to inputs and outputs, not live state.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Isn't `multiprocessing.Value` a shared state between the child processes? In the example above, no sharing between child processes is needed. That is, `n` can be different for each class. The main concern is that the class in the parent process does not reflect the changes each method call makes (to the state of a class in every child process).

Comment: @Dave: Sharing state between parent and child uses the same mechanisms needed to share with all children. Using a functional design (where you return new `Test`s instead of mutating in place) and using `pool.map`/`imap`/`imap_unordered` would let you replace the state in the parent with the newly calculated state in the child, but it's not direct sharing; `multiprocessing` is pickling and unpickling for all data sent to and from the workers.